# Recursion implementation with Class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I'm very new in JS
And i get stuck with simple(?) problem about Classes

All i need to do is just to put some string into code to make assert expression valid

```
class Rec {
    constructor() {
        let a = 0;
        this['put here'] = () => a+++a;
    }
}

let inst = new Rec();
console.assert(
    inst == 1 && inst == 3 && inst == 5
);
```

Noticed the Class has endless chain of values like

```
__proto__:
    constructor:
       prototype:
          constructor:
             prototype:
                ...etc
```

so I've tried to use `__proto__` but got a `Function.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a Function` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) or `toString`

```js
class Rec {
    constructor() {
        let a = 0;
        this['valueOf'] = () => a+++a;
    }
}

let inst = new Rec();
console.log(
    inst == 1 && inst == 3 && inst == 5
);
```

This works because of *Abstract Equality Comparison* between an object(`inst`) and a number

From the [specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3),

For the comparison `x == y`

> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>      return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

The `ToPrimitive` for an object calls the `valueOf` method if the `hint` is Number.

If you expand the expression, it looks like this: `a++ + a`. Every time `inst` is compared, `valueOf` method is called. And the sum of `a++` and `a` is returned.